# Difficulties with saving a text file using ofstream

Tags: c++, fstream, ofstream

Right now my problem seems to be focused on the saveFile function.

I will post the entire program here, so dont be ired when see a whole bunch of code... just look at the saveFile function at the bottom... I am posting all the code JUST IN CASE it will help you help me solve my problem.

Now for defining the apparent problem to you all: I can edit the file throughout the life of the console app with the updateSale function as I run it, but when I use the saveFile function and put in 'y' to save, the differences that are visible after using the updateSales function DO NOT get saved to the actual sales file called "salespeople.txt" and I do not understand why.

this is what the salespeople.txt looks like:
Schrute 25000

Halpert 20000

Vance 19000

Hudson 17995.5

Bernard 14501.5

now here is the program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>


using namespace std;
//variables--------------------------------------------------------


int lineCount = 0;
//prototypes-------------------------------------------------------
int getIndexLargest(string[], double[]);
void displaySalesPeople(string[], double[]);
bool readSalesFile(string[], double[]);
void updateSales(string[], double[]);
int saveFile(string, string[], double[], int);

int main()
{
    string fileName;
    int arrayLength;
    ifstream readSales;
    string salesPersonName[5];
    double saleAmount[5];


    bool flag = false;

    int options;
    do
    {

        cout << "1) Open sales person file. "<< endl;
        cout << "2) Display sales person information. "<< endl;
        cout << "3) Update sales. " << endl;
        cout << "4) Get best sales person. " << endl;
        cout << "5) Exit. " << endl;

        cout << "Please enter a number 1-5 to select an option." <<endl;
        cin >> options;


        if(options == 1)
        {
            flag = readSalesFile(salesPersonName, saleAmount);

        }
        else if(options == 2)
        {
            if(flag == false)
            {
                cout << "Please open sales file before selecting this option. Try again" << endl;
            }
            else
                displaySalesPeople(salesPersonName, saleAmount);

        }
        else if(options == 3)
        {
            if(flag == false)
            {
                cout << "Please open sales file before selecting this option. Try again" << endl;
            }
            else
                updateSales(salesPersonName, saleAmount);
        }
        else if(options == 4)
        {
            if(flag == false)
            {
                cout << "Please open sales file before selecting this option. Try again" << endl;
            }
            getIndexLargest(salesPersonName, saleAmount);
        }
        else if(options == 5)
        {

            char choice;
            cout << "Enter character y to save... anything else will exit without saving: " << endl;
            cin >> choice;
            if(choice == 'y')
            {

                saveFile(fileName, salesPersonName, saleAmount, arrayLength);
                cout << "File saved. " << endl;
            }
            else
            {
                cout << "closing program" << endl;
            }
        }
    }
    while(options != 5);
    return 0;

}


//functions---------------------------------
bool readSalesFile(string salesPersonName[], double saleAmount[])
{
    bool flag = false;
    ifstream readSales;

    string fileName;

    cout << "Please enter the path to your sales people file: ";
    getline(cin, fileName);
    readSales.open(fileName.c_str());

    while(readSales.fail())
    {
        cout << "Failed. Please enter the path to your sales file again: ";
        getline(cin, fileName);
        readSales.open(fileName.c_str());
    }
    if(readSales.good())
    {

        flag = true;
        cout << lineCount;

        string name = " ";
        double amount =0.00;
        int i = 0;
        while(!readSales.eof())
        {
            readSales >> name;
            readSales >> amount;
            salesPersonName[i] = name;
            saleAmount[i] = amount;
            i++;

        }
        for(i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            cout << "Sales person name: " << salesPersonName[i] << endl;
            cout << "Sale amount: $" << saleAmount[i] << endl;
     }

     readSales.close();
    }







    readSales.close();
    return flag;
}

void displaySalesPeople(string salesPersonName[], double saleAmount[])
{

    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        cout << "Sales person name: " << salesPersonName[i] << endl;
        cout << "Sale amount: $" << saleAmount[i] << endl;
    }

}
void updateSales(string salesPersonName[], double saleAmount[])
{
    bool flag = false;

    string findName;
    double moneyAmount;

    cout << "Enter name of sales person you want to modify: " << endl;
    cin >> findName;

    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        if(findName == salesPersonName[i])
        {
            cout << "Enter the sale amount you would like to modify: " << endl;
            cin >> moneyAmount;
            saleAmount[i] += moneyAmount;
            cout << saleAmount[i] << endl;

            flag = true;
        }


    }
    if(flag == false)
    {
        cout << " name not found" << endl;
    }

}

int getIndexLargest(string salesPersonName[], double saleAmount[])
{
    ifstream readSales;
    while(!readSales.eof())
    {
        double largestSale = 0.00;
        string largestSalesPerson;
        int i = 0;



        lineCount++;
        readSales >> salesPersonName[i];
        readSales >> saleAmount[i];
        if(saleAmount[i] > largestSale)
        {
            largestSale = saleAmount[i];
            largestSalesPerson = salesPersonName[i];
        }
        cout << "Best sales person : "<< largestSalesPerson << " $" <<setprecision(2)<<fixed<< largestSale << endl;

    }
}
int saveFile(string fileName, string salesPersonName[], double saleAmount[], int arrayLength)
{

    ofstream saveFile(fileName.c_str());

    saveFile.open(fileName.c_str());

    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        saveFile << salesPersonName[i] << " " << saleAmount[i] << endl;
    }

    saveFile.close();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question with an [mcve] or [SSCCE (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example)](http://sscce.org)

Comment: did you read the second paragraph of my question?

Comment: just look at the last function on the bottom of all the code... and just in case you so happen to need the rest of the code to help you then you look at it.

Answer (score 2):

**You are trying t open your file twice:**

```
ofstream saveFile(fileName.c_str()); // this opens the file

saveFile.open(fileName.c_str()); // so does this
```

*That will put the file in an error state so no writing will happen.*

**Just do this:**

```
ofstream saveFile(fileName.c_str()); // this opens the file
```

*And that should work.*

**Or else you can do this:**

```
ofstream saveFile; // this does not open the file

saveFile.open(fileName.c_str()); // but this does
```

*And that should work too.*

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out but it did not affect the negative condition of my program which still fails to save to my text file.